# Unable to import spring boot jar file in another POM spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml, executable-jar

I have 2 spring-boot applications. 1. search-engine, 2. post-engine. I am trying to include the search-engine jar into the post-engine POM file.

Here is my search-engine POM file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>com.askvedicastrologers</groupId>
<artifactId>search-engine</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>search-engine</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<description>search-engine project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>

    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

 
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is my post-engine POM file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>com.askvedicastrologers</groupId>
<artifactId>post-engine</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>post-engine</name>
<description>post-engine project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>

    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    ***<dependency>
        <groupId>com.askvedicastrologers</groupId>
        <artifactId>search-engine</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>***
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

After I mvn clean install the search-engine project, I am doing mvn clean install of post-engine which includes search-engine jar. The build is also successful. The issue is that if I try to use any service or any classes from the search-engine service inside the post-engine service, it cannot import it.

What configuration am I missing?

[See the image for errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dk8qS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, I created a base project and included these 2 projects in its POM.

Gave the packaging as POM `<packaging>pom</packaging>`.

```
   <modules>
    <module>../search-engine</module>
    <module>../post-engine</module>
</modules>
<dependencies>
    <!--  Search-Engine module dependency  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.askvedicastrologers</groupId>
        <artifactId>search-engine</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  Post-Engine module dependency  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.askvedicastrologers</groupId>
        <artifactId>post-engine</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I am currently facing the same issues with a very similar project as yours. I too set up a project with the common library for my search engine along with the REST API as the second module. But upon compilation, the common module is not recognized. It is very frustrating. I am not sure if it's relevant but the modules are built with Spring Boot. I have yet to find and answer, but yours is the most similar to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

try to manage your two projects like modules. Create a root project that will contain the two projects and declare in the parent pom your current projects like modules.

E.g. https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/

Comment: Thank you. I will go through the link. What am I doing wrong here ??
Just for my understanding, I am asking.

Comment: I don't have the exactly answer for your question, but if you build your post-engine project and you declare search-engine.jar within the dependencies tree, maven try to find that jar in the source that you declare, tipycally from maven central. Check in your project their dependencies tree and find the package **com.askvedicastrologers** within them will appears the search-engine.jar, if you don't find the package then maven never installed the dependency because maven did not find it in its repository. In this case you will install manual.